# How to access element from array of strings based on index in java

Tags: java

Here is my code to print array ,how can i print specific element from array of strings

```
 Elements dds = document.select("dd");
         String[] ddsTexts = new String[dds.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < dds.size(); i++) {
                ddsTexts[i] = dds.get(i).ownText();
                System.out.println(ddsTexts);

            }
```

Comment: This will throw `IndexOutofBoundException` for the first iteration

Comment: @sanbhat It looks like it will throw a `NullPointerException` to me. The array is the correct size, the 3rd element just isn't initialized.

Comment: ddsTesxs[i] getting all elements,need 3rd element ,what i have to do?

Comment: @Dukeling me also getting nullPointerException.

Comment: No, `ddsTesxs[i]` will only return element `i`. But you're unconditionally using `ddsTexts[3]` *within the loop*.

Comment: Calling `toString` on a `String` is largely redundant.

Answer (score 3):

if you need to print third element only
then try this

```
if(i == 2)//since array indexes starts from zero
  System.out.println(ddsTexts[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like

```
if(i==2) //index will be 2 for 3rd element
 System.out.println(ddsTexts[i].toString());
```

also since `ddsTexts` is a `String[]` even `toString()` call is not required, so

```
 if(i==2)
     System.out.println(ddsTexts[i]);
```

Comment: i want to access it from another class so is it possible to call based on index?